# Variable name change on entire code in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change a variable name with another but I have to change it manually step by step on entire code where the variable that I want to change its name is there

[image]

I want to change all `diabetes_2` values with the `diabetes_4` name

Comment: Go to `Edit` option in Jupyter Notebook page, Click on `Find and Replace`, Choose option as Replace in all cells ( having line with up and down arrow). Put `diabetes_2` in Find and put `diabetes_4`  in Replace and select `Replace All`

Comment: Please do not use images of the code, add the code in textual form with proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Enter Command Mode by pressing <kbd>esc</kbd>, followed by *find and replace* key binding <kbd>f</kbd>, so <kbd>esc</kbd> then <kbd>f</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple to replace you just have to close the ipynb file and open it with a simple notepad

Once you open it you will fing that the file is structured in a DOM format.

here you just have to find (diabetes_2) and replace(diabetes_4) the variable.

and open it with Jupyter you will find that new variable is reflected.